# How to match the first three lines in the file that contain some word

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, solaris

How to match the first three lines in the file that contain the word **racoon** ( from the top to down )

For example

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
18.2.3.122  racoon133
192.9.200.10 exemachine2
18.2.3.123  Aracoon101
10.10.10.10 jank_machine
18.2.3.124  racoon102
18.2.3.125 start10
18.2.3.125 frt100
18.2.3.128  racoon103
```

The expected results should be

```
18.2.3.122  racoon133
18.2.3.123  Aracoon101
18.2.3.124  racoon102
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '/racoon/ { print; if(++ctr == 3) exit }' filename
```

Alternatively with sed:

```
sed -n '/racoon/ { x; /.../ q; s/$/./; x; p; }' filename
```

...but perhaps most sanely with grep:

```
grep -m 3 racoon filename
```

That last one might be a GNU extension; I'm not entirely certain Solaris's grep will accept `-m 3`. Of course, there's always

```
grep racoon filename | head -n 3
```

although that doesn't short-circuit (could be a performance problem with long files).

Comment: yes on solaris the option of grep -m dosent work , but you have exelent solution with awk/sed +1

Answer (score 2):

another awk way

```
awk 'x<x+=/racoon/;x==3{exit}' file
```

or

```
awk '/racoon/&&++x;x==3{exit}' file
```